# Centred DIV appears right hand side in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Code below works fine in FF, CH etc. but doesn't get centred in IE. It goes towards to right hand side of the screen.

Any idea why?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sliding DIVs</title>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            * {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
                font-family:arial;
                font-size:12px;
            }
            #cover {
                width:100%;
                height:400px;
                background:#EEEEEE;
                text-align:center;
            }
            #slides {
                width:1024px;
                height:400px;
                margin:0px auto;
            }
            .slide {
                width:1024px;
                height:400px;
                display:none;
                position:absolute;
                border:1px solid #000000;
            }
            .slide img {
                width:1024px;
                height:400px;
            }
            .first {
                display:block;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                var timeoutId;                                                              //To store timeout id

                var slideImage = function(step)
                {
                    if (step == undefined) step = 1;                                        //If undefined then set default value

                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);                                                //Clear timeout if any

                    var indx = $('.slide:visible').index('.slide');                         //Get current image's index

                    if (step != 0)                                                          //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
                    {
                        $('.slide:visible').fadeOut();                                      //Fadeout this slide
                    }

                    indx = indx + step;                                                     //Increment for next slide

                    if (indx >= $('.slide').length)                                         //Check bounds for next slide
                    {
                        indx = 0;
                    }
                    else if (indx < 0)
                    {
                        indx = $('.slide').length - 1;
                    }

                    if (step != 0)                                                          //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
                    {
                        $('.slide:eq(' + indx + ')').fadeIn();                              //Fadein next slide
                    }

                    timeoutId = setTimeout(slideImage, 2000);                               //Set Itmeout
                };

                slideImage(0);                                                              //Start sliding

                $('#prev').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on prev
                {
                    slideImage(-1);                                                         //SlideImage with step = -1
                });

                $('#next').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on next
                {
                    slideImage(1);                                                          //SlideImage with step = 1
                });

                $('#stop').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on Pause
                {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);                                                //Clear timeout

                    $(this).hide();                                                         //Hide Pause and show Play
                    $('#play').show();
                });

                $('#play').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on Play
                {
                    slideImage(0);                                                          //Start slide image

                    $(this).hide();                                                         //Hide Play and show Pause
                    $('#stop').show();    
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="cover">
            <div id="slides">
                <div class="slide first">1</div>
                <div class="slide">2</div>
                <div class="slide">3</div>
                <div class="slide">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the margin for slides to auto and removing the 0px. I don't think that will break anything but should fix problem?

Comment: Which element is it that you want centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slide class has absolute position and is moving it outside of the container.

Add:

```
#slides {
    position:relative;
}
```

(as already suggested) and then:

```
 .slide {
    left:0px;
 }
```

Comment: When removing it, next image appears just under current image so two image appears at same time.

Comment: @Mad Max Updated it for you, you need to add a `left:0px` to make IE happy.

Answer (score 1):

Add this so you have a relative container for the `.slides`

```
#slides {
  position: relative;
 }
```

Is this what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/CXKSC/2/

Comment: Which version of IE?  I viewed my code in IE7 and it looks centered to me.  Perhaps, I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I think is much the same as @xivo said.  Works in IE, but the slides do jump around a little on transition.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Sliding DIVs</title> 
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
        <style> 
            * { 
                margin:0px; 
                padding:0px; 
                font-family:arial; 
                font-size:12px; 
            } 
            #cover { 
                width:100%; 
                height:400px; 
                background:#EEEEEE; 
                text-align:center; 
                position:absolute
            } 
            #slides { 
                width:1024px; 
                height:400px; 
                margin:0px auto; 
            } 
            .slide { 
                width:1024px; 
                height:400px; 
                display:none; 
                position:relative;
                border:1px solid #000000; 
            } 
            .slide img { 
                width:1024px; 
                height:400px; 
            } 
            .first { 
                display:block; 
            } 
            </style> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            var timeoutId;                                                              //To store timeout id 

            var slideImage = function(step) 
            { 
                if (step == undefined) step = 1;                                        //If undefined then set default value 

                clearTimeout(timeoutId);                                                //Clear timeout if any 

                var indx = $('.slide:visible').index('.slide');                         //Get current image's index 

                if (step != 0)                                                          //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout 
                { 
                    $('.slide:visible').fadeOut();                                      //Fadeout this slide 
                } 

                indx = indx + step;                                                     //Increment for next slide 

                if (indx >= $('.slide').length)                                         //Check bounds for next slide 
                { 
                    indx = 0; 
                } 
                else if (indx < 0) 
                { 
                    indx = $('.slide').length - 1; 
                } 

                if (step != 0)                                                          //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout 
                { 
                    $('.slide:eq(' + indx + ')').fadeIn();                              //Fadein next slide 
                } 

                timeoutId = setTimeout(slideImage, 2000);                               //Set Itmeout 
            }; 

            slideImage(0);                                                              //Start sliding 

            $('#prev').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on prev 
            { 
                slideImage(-1);                                                         //SlideImage with step = -1 
            }); 

            $('#next').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on next 
            { 
                slideImage(1);                                                          //SlideImage with step = 1 
            }); 

            $('#stop').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on Pause 
            { 
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);                                                //Clear timeout 

                $(this).hide();                                                         //Hide Pause and show Play 
                $('#play').show(); 
            }); 

            $('#play').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on Play 
            { 
                slideImage(0);                                                          //Start slide image 

                $(this).hide();                                                         //Hide Play and show Pause 
                $('#stop').show();     
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head> 

    <body> 
        <div id="cover"> 
            <div id="slides"> 
                <div class="slide first">1</div> 
                <div class="slide">2</div> 
                <div class="slide">3</div> 
                <div class="slide">4</div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Or another way around this probelm... Try putting all your divs on screen, and visible, with different z-index's, then change your javascript to fade each image out to no visibility?? then fade them all back in together (highest z-index will be visible) and repeat??  Not sure if oyu can fade out to 0 visibiity though... never tried